# How to load multiple csv files from local pc

Tags: python, csv

**EDIT / Solution:** *Resolved by keeping same seperators in both the csv's and removing* `.joinpath('data')`

I'm trying to work with an example python code where I need to load multiple CSV files from local AD.

I tried to load the files into datadir as :

```
datadir = Path(r'C:\Users\russel_peters\Downloads\data').resolve().joinpath('data')

filenames = {
    'spelling-bees': 'spelling-bee-winners.csv',
    'deaths': 'cdc-causes-of-death.csv',
}
```

Actual code:

How to load-path where the multiple data sets are stored.

```
datadir = Path('.').resolve().joinpath('data')

filenames = {
   'first-file': 'first-file.csv',
   'second-file': 'second-file.csv',
}

filenames = {k: datadir.joinpath(v) for k, v in filenames.items()}

for fn in filenames.values():
   assert fn.exists(), 'File not found: {}'.format(fn)


def standardize(s):
   """standardize column name."""
   res = re.sub(r'\W+', '_', s.lower())
   if res.endswith('_'):
      res = res[:-1]
   if res.startswith('_'):
      res = res[1:]
   return res
```

Comment: Please show what the full path on your hard drive to the files are

Comment: Does your solution work? You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Thank you all. I figured it myself. I guess it's because of different separators in both CSV'. I sorted the issue by removing .joinpath('data') and by keeping same separator in both csv's

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the for loop where you assert if the file exists.
Opening the file as a csv and performing whatever functions are required on the csv file.

```
for fn in filenames.values:
    if fn.exists():
        with open(fn, 'wb') as csvfile:
        ...
```